# Wordpress doesn't update htaccess after change Site Address

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how are you doing?

I need some assistance in a huge problem that I tried to solve in many ways and I could not.

I have two separated servers one answering by this url `www.mysite.com` and another by `blog.mysite.com`.

The server one aka Site (`www.mysite.com`) there is a proxy to server two aka Blog (`blog.mysite.com`).

```
.htaccess
RewriteRule ^blog/?(.*) http://blog.mysite.com/$1 [P]
```

The wordpress is installed in the Blog server. When I change the Site URL to responde by `www.mysite.com/blog` the file `.htaccess` does not update anymore.

For instance:
[image]

I get this Error:

[image]

And on W3TC:

[image]

So, if I put the Site Address equal to WordPress Address the `.htaccess` update without problems.

PS: This is not a File Permission problem, the permissions are ok. The user/group are correct.

Comment: Is the .htaccess file on a different server than the actual wordpress install?

Comment: @PanamaJack Actually there is two `.htaccess`. One in the site server and another in the blog server. The code in the site server is in the question (only proxy to blog server) and the blog htaccess is not writeable by its on server.

So if you are asking if the Wordpress `.htaccess` is in the same server that the Wordpress is installed, the answer is Yes.

Comment: I am dealing with the same issue after changing my site address. Did you figure out the solution? @diegoos

Comment: Hi @SebG, at that time we changed the insfrastructure estrategy. :\

Comment: Hello @diegoos, turns out all I needed to do was make the Site Address the same as the WordPress Address. I didn't realize that making an Alias to my AWS EBS environment still counted as a direct link to my core files. Thanks for the anawer though!

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress don't have a permission for editing .htaccess.

There're 2 solutions:

1. ".htaccess" file should have same user/group owner with PHP (for example, www-data).
2. You should give write permissions to ".htaccess." In this case give **CHMOD 666** permission for ".htaccess" file.

Comment: Hi @Zulfugar Ismayilzadeh. So, I guess is not an permission issue. The user/group is the same of Apache user and I tried to set the CHMOD to 777 and still does not work. But thanks for your answer. :)